# How can I add a permanent IP routes that survives a network restart (systemd-networkd)?

Tags: networking, routing, systemd

Given that adding routes is allowed on a node, how can I setup a persistent IP route? Currently when I use:

```
ip route add {NETWORK/MASK} via {GATEWAYIP}
```

It gets removed after every network restart.

I am using `system-networkd`.

## Things I have tried

### Using netplan

In the folder `/etc/netplan` I have only the file `50-cloud-init.yaml` (the cloud provider is OpenStack):

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            ...
            routes:
                - to: {NETWORK/MASK}
                  via: {GATEWAYIP}
                  on-link: true
```

It mentions that it is not persistent, but also adding the routes and reloading did not add the routes. No significant change in logging.

### Using systemd/network Configuration

Adding a file `ens3.network` under `/etc/systemd/network`

```
[Match]
Name=ens3

[Route]
Destination={NETWORK/MASK}
Gateway={GATEWAYIP}
GatewayOnlink=yes

[Route]
Destination={NETWORK/MASK}
Gateway={GATEWAYIP}
GatewayOnlink=yes
```

This doesn't throw any errors when inspecting `sudo journalctl -u systemd-networkd`, but also doesn't do what I am looking for as I don't see any changes.

#### Log Result

```
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd[1]: Starting Network Configuration...
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens3.network: MTUBytes= in [Link] section and UseMTU= in [DHCP]>
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: ens3: Link UP
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: ens3: Gained carrier
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: lo: Link UP
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: lo: Gained carrier
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: ens3: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: Enumeration completed
Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
```

Comment: Your configuration looks correct for what you are trying to do. Are you sure it is getting used at all? The line `Mar 09 12:19:25 node systemd-networkd[33690]: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens3.network: ...` seems to indicate that the network is being set up by netplan which creates different files in `/run/systemd/network/` instead and your `/etc/systemd/network/ens3.network` config file is just being ignored. Either add the route directly in netplan, or disable netplan alltogether and use systemd-networkd directly.

Comment: I've tried your solution with `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan...` and it worked. Would you mind making it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I updated my old answer instead, with some proposed alternative things to try to make it more robust (I wouldn't count on `/run/systemd/...` not being reverted at some point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running `netplan` (see second line of your log output), which creates config files in `/run/systemd/network/` for `systemd-networkd` to use, which means your `/etc/systemd/network/ens3.network` is being ignored.

The easiest is to add the route directly in your `netplan` configuration (`/etc/netplan/...`):

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      ...
      routes:
        - to: {NETWORK/MASK}
          via: {GATEWAYIP}
          on-link: true
```

(you should have already a file with the lines before `routes`, you just need to add the `routes` section to the `ens3` network).

**Update** (after reading your update and comment)

You say that it works for you if you just change `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan...`. Even if this works, I would not recommend keeping it there, since `/run` can be updated at any restart and be recreated by netplan (not sure why it didn't do it anyway - did you actually try a reboot, or just a `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service`? The later one would work, but if you reboot I expect this to get reverted too).

Adding the change directly to netplan obviously didn't work, since, based on your update, it looks like you are running it in some cloud that recreates the netplan file dynamically. You can disable this update the way the comment at the top tells you to, basically create a file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` with the content `network: {config: disabled}`. After doing that, you should be able to update the netplan file and this should not get overwritten any more.

Another alternative is to disable netplan altogether (to do this, it is enough to e.g. delete `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and do the change above so that your cloud provider doesn't bring it back! - back it up somewhere in case you need it again later), and then copy `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan...` to `/etc/systemd/network/ens3.network` and make your routing changes.

Comment: I am unsure about the consequences regarding disabling the clouds dynamic netplan file. I will investigate this further and come back when I have an answer. I just used `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service` so you might be right.